# Adding markers in Corona SDK for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, lua, coronasdk, marker

I'm having trouble getting the marker added. (only tried on Android devices) I want to add the marker inmediately after the map is loaded. Got it working adding a delay but couldn't make it work by just adding the marker or scaling the map again (by using `setRegion`).

I tried the following:

1.

local mapa

```
mapa=native.newMapView( 20, 20, 280, 360 )
mapa.x = display.contentCenterX
mapa.y = display.contentCenterY
mapa.mapType = "standard"
mapa:setCenter( 41.641208, -0.896030 )
mapa:addMarker(tonumber(41.641208), tonumber(-0.896030),{ 
           title = "El Rincon de la Encina", 
           subtitle = "Ofertas diarias!"})
mapa:setRegion(41.641208, -0.896030, 0.01, 0.01, false)
mapa.isLocationVisible=true
```

2. This one works correctly

```
local mapa

    mapa=native.newMapView( 20, 20, 280, 360 )
    mapa.x = display.contentCenterX
    mapa.y = display.contentCenterY
    mapa.mapType = "standard"
    mapa:setCenter( 41.641208, -0.896030 )
    mapa.isLocationVisible=true


local function listener:timer( event )
     mapa:addMarker(tonumber(41.641208), tonumber(-0.896030),{ 
               title = "El Rincon de la Encina", 
               subtitle = "Ofertas diarias!"})
end

timer.performWithDelay( 30000, listener )
```

Only if the timer calls the function after the map is loaded I get the wanted result.

The reason for adding `tonumber` was to make sure Corona got the number correctly.

3. Applying the solution handed over by @AniV

   local attempts = 0

   ```
    mapa=native.newMapView( 20, 20, 280, 360 )
   mapa.x = display.contentCenterX
   mapa.y = display.contentCenterY
   mapa.mapType = "standard"
   mapa:setCenter( 41.641208, -0.896030 )
   mapa:setRegion(41.641208, -0.896030, 0.01, 0.01, false)
   mapa.isLocationVisible=true

   local function locationHandler( event )
       local currentLocation = myMap:getUserLocation()
       local rinconEncinaLat = 41.641208
       local rinconEncinaLon=-0.896030
       if ( currentLocation.errorCode or ( currentLocation.latitude == 0 and currentLocation.longitude == 0 ) ) then
          attempts = attempts + 1

           if ( attempts > 10 ) then
               native.showAlert( "No GPS Signal", "Can't sync with GPS.", { "Okay" } )
           else
               timer.performWithDelay( 2000, locationHandler )
           end
       else

           mapa:setCenter( rinconEncinaLat, rinconEncinaLon )
           mapa:addMarker( rinconEncinaLat, rinconEncinaLon,{ 
              title = "El Rincon de la Encina", 
              subtitle = "Ofertas diarias!"})
       end
   end

   locationHandler()
   ```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to repeatedly queue the location hardware until it receives a proper response, then call this function. See the example in [object:getUserLocation()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Map/getUserLocation.html) for details.

Comment: At first I thought it would work because it does the same as my second try but with a function to control exactly when the map is loaded.

I will edit my post with the code I wrote trying your solution.
Is it possible that it takes longer than 2 sec after the map is loaded to add the marker?

Comment: I've tried everything and it only works if I use getUserLocation() as the location where to add the pin. It doesn't work with other locations